# Cache busting with Django

Tags: python, django, caching, static, cdn

I'm working on a website built with Django.
When I'm doing updates on the static files, the users have to hard refresh the website to get the latest version.
I'm using a CDN server to deliver my static files so using the built-in static storage from Django.
I don't know about the best practices but my idea is to generate a random string when I redeploy the website and have something like `style.css?my_random_string`.
I don't know how to handle such a global variable through the project (Using Gunicorn in production).
I have a RedisDB running, I can store the random string in it and clear it on redeployment.
I was thinking to have this variable globally available in templates with a `context_processors`.

What are your thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my work around :

On deployment (from a bash script), I get the shasum of my css style.
I put this variable inside the environment.

I have a context processor for the template engine that will read from the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Django's built-in contrib.staticfiles app already does this for you; see  [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) and [CachedStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/cachedstaticfilesstorage).

Comment: As I said, I'm using a CDN Server, I'm already using a different storage system than the default one.